# Store multiple email addresses from single line to a list/collection

Tags: excel, vba

So I am downloading a storing a JSON file in my temp folder and reading it as such (the output is a single line of string):

```
Dim strFileContent As String
Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = FreeFile
Open strFilePath For Input As #iFile
strFileContent = Input(LOF(iFile), iFile)
Close #iFile
```

This file is of the following structure:

[image: JSON struct]

Now the emails are very standard format: `first.last@example.com`. Instead of going to a full JSON parsing library, is there a way to extract just the emails to a list from the string `strFileContent`?

Here's a sample text of the JSON on how the email looks, just in case: `"work_email":{"display_name":"Work Email","data":"alpha.beta@example.com"},`

I was looking at `https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON`, but I was hoping for a simpler RegEx solution (instead of a JSON parser) because if the API gives me a XML file tomorrow, my code will be obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend going the JSON parser route, it'll be much more reliable. However, if you want a regex solution, maybe this will work.

```
Public Function ExtractEmails(ByVal InputString, Optional pattern As String = "\"":""\w+@\w+\.\w+") As Object
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .pattern = pattern
        Set ExtractEmails = .Execute(InputString)
    End With
End Function

Public Sub Example()
    Dim someString As String
    Dim emails     As Object
    Dim email      As Variant

    someString = "klasdkjasdkjha abc1@abc.com ""data"":""abc2@abc.com"" ""data"":""abc3@abc.com"" ""data"":""abc4@abc.com"" asdkjhaksjdhaksjhd"
    Set emails = ExtractEmails(someString)

    For Each email In emails
        Debug.Print Replace(Replace(email, """", vbNullString), ":", vbNullString)
    Next

End Sub
```

Returns (abc1@abc.com doesn't match the pattern, it should precede ":"):

```
abc2@abc.com
abc3@abc.com
abc4@abc.com
```